# php post method in update query is not working

Tags: php

my database **insert** has one table table1. table1 has 3 columns     **user,id,time**   i want to update time column of table1 by posting a value from a php file but my update query is showing error:

> Error: UPDATE table1 set time=1:40 WHERE id=12
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':40 WHERE id=12' at line 1

i have already inserted id column value in table1 ..what should i do?here is my code

**update.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="newadd.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name='name'><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**insertupdate.php**

```
 <?php
include('insertjoincon.php');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$tim = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "UPDATE table1 set time=$tim WHERE id=12";

if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

but when i use `$tim = 4` then table updates but when use post then it shows error.

Comment: that string should be quoted `'$tim'`, but thats not the case, you should use prepared statements as your codes are vulnerable to sql injection. and the your notification message is odd, it says `new record created` but you're actually updating a row

Comment: `$tim` must be in quotes ... these are the basics of SQL ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because of `:` in the value. Wrap it with `'`s. It would be -

```
set time='1:40' 

$sql = "UPDATE table1 set time='$tim' WHERE id=12";
```

Comment: yea ofcourse i have accepted your ans..but i don't know why it is not showing :(

Comment: is this a valid syntax ? remember to escape strings.

Comment: @Raptor valid syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Not Proper Syntax So Try this Code:

```
$tim = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "UPDATE table1 set time='".$tim."' WHERE id=12";
```

or

```
$sql = "UPDATE table1 set time='$tim' WHERE id=12";
```

Comment: This is VERY dangerous. Always escape input from `$_POST` before applying to SQL.

Comment: I agree  but programmer can understand.

Answer (score 1):

Missing quotes around time (and don't forget to sanitize data from users).

```
$sql = "UPDATE table1 set time='" . $conn->real_escape_string($tim) . "' WHERE id = 12";
```